# Doubt about a proof of Proposition 4.20 of "Algebraic Geometry" by Milne.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, algebraic-geometry

I have a doubt about one part of this following proposition:

**Proposition 4.20:** Every local regular ring of dimension one is a principal  ideal domain.

**Proof**: Let $A$ be such a ring, and let $\mathfrak{m}=(\pi)$ be its maximal ideal.
... ...
... ...
... ...
By assumption, there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ properly contained in $\mathfrak{m}$. ....

$----------------------------$

And then the proof goes on, but my doubt is with that part.

If $A$ is a local regular ring of dimension one, as $\mathfrak{m}$ is prime also, it would be the only proper ideal, so if its Krull's dimension is equal to $1$, then the only possible prime ideals are $0$ and $\mathfrak{m}$.
Therefore, when in the proof it is said that exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ properly contained in $\mathfrak{m}$... then is necessarily $\mathfrak{p}=0\ \ ?$
You can continue the proof using a general $\mathfrak{p}$, but the proof becomes easier if you use that $\mathfrak{p}=0$. But I am not sure if I am understanding it correctly. So the question would be... is necessarily $\mathfrak{p}=0\ \ ?$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any proper ideal $I$ is contained in a maximal ideal $m$, if there is only one maximal ideal and it is principal then $m = (\pi)$ and we can repeat with the ideal $\pi^{-1} I$ until eventually  we obtain $\pi^{-k} I = (1), I = (\pi^k)$. The possible failure of $I$ contained in  every power of $(\pi)$ must be discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not assumed explicitly in the hypotheses of the result that $A$ is a domain. The assumption that $A$ is local implies that every proper (e.g., prime) ideal of $A$ is contained in $\mathfrak{m}$, and the assumption that $A$ has dimension one implies that there must be a prime ideal of $A$ distinct from $\mathfrak{m}$. That the only such ideal is in fact $0$ (which *implies* that $A$ is a domain) is deduced from the additional hypothesis that $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by a regular element of $A$.

Comment: Thank you. But could I use that as $A$ is regular then the number of generators of $\mathfrak{m}$ is equal to $1$ (the dimension) and then $\mathfrak{p}$ must be equal to $0$ because of that? (If it weren't $0$ then $\mathfrak{m}$ would be generated by $\mathfrak{p}$. I am sorry if I am saying something dumb, but I am learning algebra by my own and I have some misconceptions.

Comment: Dear @Alfredo, How are you linking the assumption that $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal (and that $\dim(A)=1$) with your statement "[if] it [$\mathfrak{p}$] weren't $0$ then $\mathfrak{m}$ would be generated by $\mathfrak{p}$?" Are you thinking that, if $\mathfrak{p}$ were not zero, then it would require at least one generator, but that because $\mathfrak{m}$ itself requires only one generator, this would force $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{m}$? This is not valid.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about it and it wouldn't definitely force $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{m}$. I don't want to be stubborn, but could I use then: $0$ is prime, and contained in $\mathfrak{m}$. Any other $\mathfrak{p}$ contained in $\mathfrak{m}$ would induce $0 \subset \mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{m}$, but as $dim(A)=1$, then $\mathfrak{p}$ must be $0$ or $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Dear @Alfredo, Unless you already know that $A$ is an integral domain, then you do not know that $0$ is a prime ideal. This was the main point of my answer.